# MySQL Query to integrate information from 3 tables (with plenty of obstacles)

Tags: mysql

Background: In an experiment bees are glued number tags on their backs which and their choices in a lab are recorded. Not having enough number tags (2 digits and a few color options) they need to be reused. However, a tag is only reused after the one carrying it dies. Therefore, in the data structure we occasionally see bee identifiers but the only way to know whether it's from the same bee or not is by looking in another table to see whether the bee died or not.

The Tables: 
The choices bees make

```
CREATE TABLE `exp8` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bee_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `choice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hover_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `antennate_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `land_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `landing_position` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` longtext,
  `validity` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=264;

LOCK TABLES `exp8` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `exp8` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `exp8` (`id`, `bee_id`, `date_time`, `choice`, `hover_duration`, `antennate_duration`, `land_duration`, `landing_position`, `remarks`, `validity`)
VALUES
    (1,NULL,'2013-05-14 15:38:31','right',1,0,0,NULL,NULL,1),
    (2,NULL,'2013-05-18 10:27:15','left',1,0,0,NULL,NULL,1),
    (3,'G5','2013-05-18 11:44:44','left',0,0,4,'yellow',NULL,1),
    (4,'G5','2013-06-01 10:00:00','left',0,0,4,'yellow',NULL,1);
```

The time of birth and death tags

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bee_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `colony_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `events` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `worker_age` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tagged_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=406;

LOCK TABLES `tags` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tags` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `bee_id`, `tag_date`, `colony_id`, `events`, `worker_age`, `tagged_by`)
VALUES
    (1,'G5','2013-05-08',1,'birth','Adult','ET'),
    (2,'G5','2013-05-20',NULL,'death','Adult','ET'),
    (3,'G5','2013-05-29',1,'birth','Adult','ET');
```

And the stimuli that are being displayed in the lab

```
CREATE TABLE `stimuli_schedule` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `left_side` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `right_side` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `scheduled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50;

LOCK TABLES `stimuli_schedule` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `stimuli_schedule` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `stimuli_schedule` (`id`, `left_side`, `right_side`, `start_datetime`, `scheduled`)
VALUES
    (1,'LS1','LS2','2013-05-14 12:00:00',NULL),
    (2,'LS2','LS1','2013-05-15 11:44:00',NULL),
    (3,'LS1','LS2','2013-05-30 11:09:00',NULL);
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
bee_id     CHOICE_DATETIME     LEFT_SIDE     RIGHT_SIDE     CHOICE
===================================================================
NULL       2013-05-14 15:38:31     LS1          LS2           right
G5         2013-05-18 10:27:15     LS2          LS1           left
G5         2013-06-01 10:00:00     LS1          LS2           left
```

Thanks to the generous help of @GordonLinoff and @jcsanyi there are two related MySQL queries that achieve part of the solution:

This bit shows each individual bee's choice, assuming that a bee's ID is unique:

```
select bee_id, count(case when choice="left" then 1 else NULL end) as leftCount, count(case when choice="right" then 1 else NULL end) as rightCount
  from exp8 e
  left join stimuli_schedule ss on ss.start_datetime <= e.date_time
  left join stimuli_schedule ss2 on ss2.start_datetime <= e.date_time
  where (bee_id IS NOT NULL) AND (ss2.left_side IN ('LA1','HS1') AND ss2.right_side IN('HS1','LA1'))
  group by bee_id
```

This bit is capable of showing a bees length of life, and distinguishes between reused tags:

```
select t.bee_id, (case when t.death_date is null then 'Alive' else 'Dead' end) as status, 
        t.tag_date, t.death_date, (case when t.death_date is not null then timediff(t.death_date,t.tag_date) else timediff(NOW(),t.tag_date) end) as age
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.tag_date
              from tags t2
              where t2.bee_id = t.bee_id and
                    t2.events = 'death' and
                    t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date
              limit 1
             ) as death_date
      from tags t
      where t.events = 'birth'
     ) t
group by t.bee_id, t.tag_date;
```

I am having trouble combining the two queries to produce the desired output. Here is my attempt:

```
select t.bee_id, count(case when choice="left" then 1 else NULL end) as leftCount,
       count(case when choice="right" then 1 else NULL end) as rightCount, 
       (case when t.death_date is null then 'Alive' else 'Dead' end) as status, 
       t.tag_date, t.death_date, 
       (case when t.death_date is not null 
             then timediff(t.death_date,t.tag_date) 
             else timediff(NOW(),t.tag_date) end) as "age (hours)"
from exp8 e, (select t.*,
             (select t2.tag_date
              from tags t2
              where t2.bee_id = t.bee_id and
                    t2.events = 'death' and
                    t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date
              limit 1
             ) as death_date
      from tags t
      where t.events = 'birth'
     ) t
left join stimuli_schedule ss on ss.start_datetime <= e.date_time
left join stimuli_schedule ss2 on ss2.start_datetime <= e.date_time
where (e.bee_id IS NOT NULL)
group by t.bee_id, t.tag_date;
```

For reasons beyond my understanding, the left e.date_time portion is causing an "unknown column" error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you create a table just for the bees who died and load from it?

Comment: Not a single one of your example queries produce any output with your data. (Unless, of course, I missed something.) Edit your question, paste in CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT statements that we can use without having to reverse engineering your descriptions.

Comment: Sorry to frustrate @MikeSherrill'Catcall' -- I updated the question as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

The way it stands now the `JOIN` operators relate to the derived table t, not to exp8 as you apparently intended. That's what you get by mixing two different join syntaxes. You would also want to join t to exp8 on bee_id, I presume.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio -- The query now does not produce an error but runs indefinitely without generating any records...

Comment: You cannot claim that it runs indefinitely after only 17 minutes.

Comment: Fair point, it runs for ~16 minutes without producing results. There are not many records: tags:261, stimuli_schedule:49 and exp8:403

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more in the database design itself. Behavour is attributed to a bee. That bee needs to be uniquely identified. As such, a primary key for the bee is needed and you can code the behavour according to that bee id.

The trick is, when you process the tag, then you need to determine which bee currently has that tag. Easily done with a table that lists the tags currently deployed. When a bee dies and the tag is re-assigned or retired, then the active tags list can subsequently be updated.

If you can see where I'm going with this, the selects you're doing in the data analysis phase are overly complex because they're trying to imitate the missing primary key and needlessly apply it to your behavour entries. Correct the design and your data analysis will be many times faster and your queries far simpler.

Comment: Thanks @hsikcah -- this doesn't change the need for a process to determine when a tag has been reused -- whether that is done by assigning a unique key, or by doing it 'on the fly' each time i want an output seems like a trivial modification in the db design. Am I missing something?

Comment: The reason your queries are insane is that you are trying to emulate the primary key missing from your design. Adding a few indices would help with the running time but the best longterm solution is to adjust the design so it is aligned with the needs of your queries.Normalize out the log of when you retag the bees so you can retain the history for auditing purposes but a bee is still unique entity with a unique bee id. The tag is only unique given the time period it is krazy-glued to the bombus impatens buttocks.